# jquery jScrollPane ipad issue

Tags: iphone, jquery, ipad, jscrollpane

I am pulling my hair out with an scroll issue with iPad/iPhone...

I am using the fantastic jScrollPane plugin which works a treat on desktop browsers but on iPad/iPhone the div doesnt scroll (to do with touch events or something?)

I have tried all the fixes:

http://snipplr.com/view/41051/jscrollpane-ipadiphoneipodios-scoll-support/
(i think old version of jScrollPane so not sure where this fits in)

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/
just didnt work full stop seemingly

https://github.com/aFarkas/jScrollPane/commit/553612cb26a390004a9aa63ab0511e2b668bcf8c#diff-1
script/jquery.touchdrag.js: applied and didnt seem to work either

Any ideas anyone? My client is impatient :/

A.

Comment: just to add:https://github.com/aFarkas/jScrollPane/commit/553612cb26a390004a9aa63ab0511e2b668bcf8c#diff-1 works if you use the supplied jScrollPane to (beta 5) I was using beta 6 which didnt work

Comment: Glad you figured out a way to get it to work... I will integrate that patch into the up to date version of jScrollPane ASAP (jScrollPane is my plugin) - I'm really busy with client work at the moment so haven't had a chance... This is the issue where I am keeping track of all of the possible solutions: https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues#issue/14

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this questions is a bit old, anyway, I post my research here:

My version is jscrollpane v2.0.0beta10

I am also using [Kelvin Luck's jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) directly from his site.
I have just tried our website, it seems newer version is working without problem.

Just made a [scroll demo here extracted from my site](http://zenrity.com/demo/jscroll.html)
Only using the basic code like

```
$('.scrollbar-area').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    horizontalGutter: 10 // must set for IE running properly
});
```

I have tested in iPad 2.0(iOS 6.01), I have no iPhone for testing. 
When I drag the content, it work in iPad. The scrollbar itself does not work though.